# ReferenceError: link is not defined (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, visual-studio-code

Столкнулся с проблемой. Установил Node.JS (6.11.4).
Запускаю рабочий код через терминал в Visual Studio Code (`node имя_файла`).
Подключаю модули (`npm install имя_модуля`).
Выдает ошибку:

> "ReferenceError: link is not defined".

Код у всех запускается, но у меня нет:

```
var request = require('request'),
cheerio = require('cheerio'),
fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path'),
res_arr = [],
ind = 0,
count_posts = 500;

var news_base_url = 'http://need.url?p=';

var file_json = path.resolve(__dirname, 'parse_file.json'); 

get_page_content(news_base_url + 0, 0);

function get_page_content( url, i ) {
request(url, function ( error, response, body ) {

    if( !error ) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body),
            newses = $('.news-item');

        newses.each(function () {
            var self = $(this),
                cont = self.find('.news-text');


            res_arr[ind++] = {
                title: cont.find('.title').text(),
                date : cont.find('.date').text(),
                link : cont.find('a').attr('href'),
                img  : cont.find('img').attr('src')
            }

            get_post_content(link, ind);

            ind++;
        });

    } else {
        console.log("Произошла ошибка: " + error);
    }
});
}

function get_post_content( link, array_index ) {
request(link, function ( error, response, body ) {

    if( !error ) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body, {decodeEntities: false});

        res_arr[array_index].content = $('.text').html();

    } else {
        console.log("Произошла ошибка: " + error);
    }

    if( count_posts-- <= 0 ){
        write_parse_res( file_json, JSON.stringify(res_arr) );
    }
});
}

function write_parse_res( file_json, str ) {
fs.writeFile(file_json, str, function ( err ) {
    if( err ) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Добавил все');
    }
});
}
```

Comment: А откуда у вас берется переменная `link`? Вот тут `get_post_content(link, ind);`

Comment: Я весь материал читал отсюда 
https://sawtech.ru/tehno-blog/parsing-sajtov-na-nodejs/

Comment: Поздравляю, ваш самоучитель -- говно. Выкиньте его на помойку и найдите приличный, без логических ошибок в коде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно, что код у всех запускается. Очевидно ошибка возникает в вызове

```
get_post_content(link, ind);
```

здесь **link** не определена. Судя по коду в get_post_content должно передаваться содержимое поля link

```
link : cont.find('a').attr('href'),
```

замените вызов например на

```
get_post_content(res_arr[ind-1].link, ind);
```

и очень сомнительно выглядит двойное увеличение индекса **ind**. Сначала в

```
res_arr[ind++]
```

потом (двумя строчками ниже) в

```
ind++;
```

Comment: Теперь: "Cannot set property 'content' of undefined"

Comment: @AntonKolesnik Проблема в индексах, как и написано в ответе. Из-за двойного увеличения в строке `res_arr[array_index].content = $('.text').html();` происходит ошибка, т.к. `res_arr` undefined.